# Indy 10 - IdSMTP.Connect raising "Could not load SSL library."

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, indy, delphi-6

Here is my configuration:

```
IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
```

I've downloaded the OpenSSL from [here](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/), both `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are in the same folder of my application.

The Indy version is: 10.0.52

The following command is working on my machine:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

How to properly connect in a TLS enable SMTP server, in my case Gmail, using Indy?

It seems like `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load` could not find the address to the following procedures, among others:

```
  @IdSslSessionGetId := LoadIndyFunction(fn_SSL_SESSION_get_id);
  @IdSslSessionGetIdCtx := LoadIndyFunction(fn_SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx);
  @IdSslCtxGetVersion := LoadIndyFunction(fn_SSL_CTX_get_version);
  @IdSslCtxSetOptions := LoadIndyFunction(fn_SSL_CTX_set_options);

  @iddes_set_odd_parity := LoadFunctionCLib(fn_des_set_odd_parity);
  @iddes_set_key := LoadFunctionCLib(fn_des_set_key);
  @iddes_ecb_encrypt := LoadFunctionCLib(fn_des_ecb_encrypt);
```

This is the message returned from `WhichFailedToLoad`:

```
 SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy 
 X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy 
 X509_get_notBefore_indy 
 X509_get_notAfter_indy 
 SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy 
 SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy 
 SSL_CTX_get_version_indy 
 SSL_CTX_set_options_indy 
 des_set_odd_parity 
 des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt
```

Comment: I am following this [tutorial](http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html)

Comment: I believe the problem is the correct version of the dll. Do I have to test each one of them?

Comment: Here is [`the topic`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=406858) about the same version as you use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, Remy. And thank you TLama, for your time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a quote from the following discussion in the Embarcadero forums:

[OpenSSL Version to work with indy 10.0.52](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63352)

> Indy 8, 9, and early 10 versions used custom-built OpenSSL DLLs because 
>   OpenSSL did not expose everything Indy needed access to, so Indy had to add 
>   a few custom functions to the DLLs. Later Indy 10 versions switched to the 
>   official OpenSSL DLLs.
>
> Indy's custom OpenSSL DLLs are no longer distributed anywhere (that I know 
>   of), but you can try this archived download:
>
> http://web.archive.org/web/20071022121646/http://www.intelicom.si/www.nsf/2434100e396ad3f3c125705100369374/d6b8e150fe453facc1257082006fc8b9/$FILE/indy_openssl096g.zip

Some old Indy-specific OpenSSL DLLs are available in Fulgan's [SSL Archive folder](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/).

10.0.52 is an outdated release of Indy 10.  There have been a lot of changes to Indy 10 since that release.  You really should upgrade to a [modern Indy 10 release](http://ww2.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx), and then you can use the latest OpenSSL DLLs that are available in Fulgan's [SSL main folder](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

Comment: The link to both the embarcadero forums and the modern indy10 release seem to have died.