# Error "Could not load SSL library" on Android with TidHTTP

Tags: android, delphi, ssl, indy

I'm trying to download a file with TIdHTTP.Get in Delphi Seattle. It's an app for android and all my attempts fails. All i get it's the same error "Could not load SSL library". This is the procedure:

```
procedure TfrmMain.DownloadPicture(const AURL: string);
var
  MeS: TMemoryStream;
  cidSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  cidHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  cidHTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  cidSSL:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  Mes := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    cidHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
    cidHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
    cidSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    cidSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    cidSSL.StartSSL;
    cidHTTP.Get(AURL, Mes);
  except
    on E : Exception do
      begin showmessage('Error: '+E.Message);
      end;
  end;
  Mes.Position := 0;
  frmImage.Image.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Mes);
end;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are *NOT* using Android 6 Marshmallow, OpenSSL should be working fine on Android.  When you get the "could not load" error, you can call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why OpenSSL could not be loaded.  If your device does not have OpenSSL pre-installed, you can deploy the OpenSSL binaries with your app, and use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to tell Indy where to load them from.

That being said, starting with Android 6 Marshmallow, [Google no longer supports OpenSSL](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2015/10/17/boringssl.html) on Android. It has been replaced with a custom fork named [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/), which [Indy does not fully support yet](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/64884) (although *some* BoringSSL-related changes have been made to Indy after Seattle's release).  So, if you are having trouble with using Indy SSL/TLS on Android 6, you can try upgrading to the latest [Github snapshot](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy) to see if it helps.

BoringSSL makes some *major* changes to the OpenSSL API interface (dropping functions, changing data types, etc), so it is not backwards-compatible with existing OpenSSL code.  But to make matters worse, BoringSSL uses the same library filenames as OpenSSL, and is pre-loaded at device startup, so it is not possible to deploy custom-built OpenSSL library binaries with your Android app. Android will simply use the pre-loaded BoringSSL binaries when the app tries to load the OpenSSL library filenames at runtime (regardless of whether you call Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function).

Indy operates at the NDK level of Android, not the Java level, so to make Indy avoid BoringSSL would require users to either:

1. recompile the OpenSSL libraries with new filenames that don't conflict with BoringSSL (AFAIK no known version of this is available), and then update Indy to use those filenames.
2. compile the OpenSSL source code directly into their Android app. Indy is not currently setup to support static-linking of OpenSSL on any platform other than iOS, but this should be a minor change to update Indy's `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static` unit with the relevant definitions if someone can produce viable `.a` files for OpenSSL on Android. I do know of at least one user attempting this route, but that user has not had success yet (errors getting the source code to fully link correctly).
3. switch to Android's higher-level Java-based crypto APIs.  This is Google's preferred solution.  But Indy does not support it at this time.  Doing so would require writing a whole new set of `TIdStack` and `TIdIOHandler` classes for Android socket I/O and SSL/TLS, using JNI calls to access the Java APIs.  But this has performance and threading issues that need to be dealt with.

So, there is no known viable workaround available at this time to make Indy SSL/TLS work on Android 6+.

---

**Update**: a user in the Embarcadero forums was able to find OpenSSL `.so` files that are compatible with Indy and work on Android 6:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=211089

> After many reports of my apps crashing if installed in Android 6 devices I've searched the net for some tips and the couple of needed .so compiled files, 1.02 version, added the two files to the play store deployment of my apps (assets\internal) and changed the Indy's path calling
>
> IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath)
>
> in the OnCreate of my datamodule.
>
> After those modifications of my code my Apps run perfectly on my brand new S7 with Android 6.0.1, and on all the other recent Android devices (tested using the Play Store deployment).
>
> And now the Google warning pops up telling me that the OpsnSSL files deployed with my apps are not of the minimum required 1.02f version (or 1.01r).... and so my post in this forum.
>
> ...
>
> Anyway you can download here the latest .so files, the ones that I deploy at this moment:
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7AxqW32K0oXWW9nUk9qaFpHT0k/view?usp=sharing

Another user in the same discussion also seems to have some success as well:

> Ive been running on android 6 loading the .so libraries just fine for months. The new problem is we need to compile new versions of the openssl libraries. Cygwin is not working correctly to compile for me so im switching to a linux install to create them (if possible) https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Build_the_OpenSSL_Library_2
>
> heres a repository you can grab some current prebuilt ones https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt.git

---

**Update**: The following (German) forum discussion provides OpenSSL 1.0.2g binaries for Android (and iOS Simulator) to registered users. They do not display the security warning in the Google Play store:

http://www.delphipraxis.net/188736-kompilierte-openssl-bibliotheken-fuer-android.html

[OpenSSL 1.0.2g Android.zip](http://www.delphipraxis.net/attachments/45044d1459512328-kompilierte-openssl-bibliotheken-fuer-android-openssl-1.0.2g-android.zip)

[OpenSSL 1.0.2g iOS Simulator.zip](http://www.delphipraxis.net/attachments/45045d1459512384-kompilierte-openssl-bibliotheken-fuer-android-openssl-1.0.2g-ios-simulator.zip)

---

**Update**: the Android binaries for OpenSSL 1.0.2g are now available in the Embarcadero Attachments forum:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=211147

Then, to load OpenSSL instead of BoringSSL, follow these steps:

1. Add the 2 `.so` files to your project deployment and set them to deploy to the `.\assets\internal\` folder
2. add the `System.StartupCopy` unit as the first unit in your DPR's `uses` clause.
3. call `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath)` at app startup.

---

**Update**: OpenSSL 1.0.1t and 1.0.2h binaries are now in the Embarcadero Attachments forum:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=211147

---

**Update**: the binaries have now been posted on Indy's Fulgan mirror:

http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

---

**Update**: Indy is no longer using the Fulgan mirror for hosting OpenSSL binaries. They are now in their own GitHub repo:

https://www.indyproject.org/2020/06/16/openssl-binaries-moved-to-github/

https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Comment: Thank you Remy! I'm using Android 6 Marshmallow. By now, i had to figure out another solution to my problem and worked, but I'm sure going to face this problem in the future again and your answer helped a lot.

Comment: I'm upset, I'm angry, I'm desperate. I hate Google for doing this. I hate Embarcadero leaving no option to use SSL/TLS with Android 6 (this is a death sentence today... Apps without net encryption? Hello?). One reason I keep strugling with using Delphi. Always such big problems. On the other hand, I understand the point behind Google's decision a little bit to let everything pass through their OS. Delphi was always something special (not native, etc.). Even more I'm happy to have helpful people like Remy and the guys who found this files. At least Google called their fork correctly: BoringSSL.

Comment: came here years later. As Remy mentioned you need to download the so files. After downloading go to Project -->Deployment and Add those so files. Edit the remote path. You are done!

Comment: IdOpenSSLSetLibPath not found, what can I do?

Comment: @BDuarte `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` is in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit. Make sure that unit is in your `uses` clause

Answer (score 2):

Just swap the TidHTTP component for TNetHTTPClient

Comment: How is this helping the poster when he already accepted very detailed answer that already received plenty of up-votes?

Comment: You don't even have to be very smart to understand how it helps.
But I will try to explain as if I was talking to a child. You remove a problematic component and in its place, keeping all the properties you insert a new component, no download, no external file. Why would you stick the pieces of a broken glass together if you have a new glass at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a new OpenSSL library and an older Indy version. Check this:
[Indy 10 - IdSMTP.Connect raising "Could not load SSL library."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050325/indy-10-idsmtp-connect-raising-could-not-load-ssl-library)

Comment: Alexandre, I'm using Delphi Seattle and Indy version is 10.6.2.5298. Still, those steps seens to be for Windows.

Comment: There is only one Indy source code. Older versions of Indy don't support new OpenSSL, doesn't matter the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are versions for 32/64 bits.
Make sure you have the correct version of the files.

See [this FTP](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) for correct version.

Other mirror for download binaries [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and this works:

```
  procedure TfPrecos.GetImageByUrl(URL: string);
  var
    Strm: TMemoryStream;
    vIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    cidSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  begin
  IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath);  //libcrypto.so and libssl.so in ./assets/internal
    vIdHTTP.IOHandler := cidSSL;
    cidSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; // version 2.3
    cidSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    cidSSL.StartSSL;
    try
      vIdHTTP.Get(URL, Strm);
      if (Strm.Size > 0) then
      begin
        Strm.Position := 0;
        try
          Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Strm);
        finally
       
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Strm.DisposeOf;
      vIdHTTP.DisposeOf;
    end;

  end;
```

Comment: IdOpenSSLSetLibPath not found, what can I do?

Comment: @BDuarte `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` is in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit. Make sure that unit is in your `uses` clause

Comment: @EdimarPinheiro there is no need to call `cidSSL.StartSSL`, in fact DON'T call it as it will try to begin the TLS handshake, but you don't have a valid socket yet to transmit it with. Also, you are not creating the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object anyway, so `cidSSL` is an invalid pointer.