# OpenSSl library for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe, indy10

Where it is possible to download OpenSSL library for Android 7.0?
From this subject I took for Android 6 [Error "Could not load SSL library" on Android with TidHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105600/error-could-not-load-ssl-library-on-android-with-tidhttp)

Comment: Indy does not have any OpenSSL files for Android 7 yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [new components for REST in last versions of Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client) you can connect HTTPS without SSL libraries.

¿Can you change TidHttp for `THTTPClient`?

[Here you can find a sample article](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/download-an-image-in-background-with-android-services) that explain how to download an image from web using this component. Works in Android and no need external libraries.