# Can I use Indy in Android and iOS apps?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

I am using this code to retrieve emails using Indy pop3

```
IdPOP3.Connect;
  try
    liMessages := IdPOP3.CheckMessages;
    Label4.Text := 'CheckMessages: ' + IntToSTr(liMessages);
    lMsg := TIdMessage.Create;
    try
      IdPOP3.Retrieve(1, lMsg);
      Itm := ListView1.Items.Add;
      Itm.Text := lMsg.MsgId;

      for liCount := 0 to lMsg.MessageParts.Count-1 do
        if lMsg.MessageParts[liCount] is TIdText then
          Memo1.Lines.AddStrings((lMsg.MessageParts[liCount] as TIdText).Body);
    finally
      lMsg.Free;
    end;

  finally
    IdPOP3.Disconnect;
  end;
```

but I get error `Could not load SSL library` I know this because I should include `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` files but these are for windows ? so I can not use Indy pop3 for Android and iOS ?

Thanks to Victoria I got the Android files and deployed both on my Android 7 device

Comment: [See related...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37105600/8041231)

Comment: Thanks alot I found the android files in `http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL` but what about iOS where to get them ?

Comment: @Wel http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html

Comment: The OpenSSL static libs for iOS are also available from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/